# All Sprinkler Heads Leaking

Tags: sprinkler-system

**Introduction**

I have been installing a brand new sprinkler system into my yard. I have ran most of the water lines but have a temporary above ground set up right now, as my idea is to adjust their locations before I bury them.

**Problem**

[image]

As shown, each head leaks through many of the screw holes on the top! Every single one leaks like this so I must be missing something very obvious.  These are [RainBird 5000](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MTMV9L5) heads, and I've installed the 8.0 nozzles. Any advice or things for me to try, I am willing.

I did unscrew the top from the bottom housing and the rubber seal looks in tact, especially since they are brand new.

Comment: not enough water pressure to run that sprinkler head... it needs to pop up further to seal properly ... how many heads are running at the same time?

Comment: 3 at one time. I just tested and I have about 7 gal / min as my flow rate going into the line

Comment: insert smallest available nozzles ... then work up to larger sizes

Comment: Ah that's a great idea

Answer (score 4):

I initially had all 3 sprinkler heads set to 8.0 nozzles which was too much for my flowx rate of 7 gal / min to handle.  I started with 1.0 nozzles on all 3 locations, then sized one up at a time.

The result was 3.0 nozzles on all 3 locations.

The leaking coming out of the top of the head was caused by the sprinkler head unable to get enough pressure to lift itself up,  resulting in it not fully sealing